# Get the IP Address of Flask server as string in Python?

Tags: python, flask, networking

Whenever I launch my Flask server, I get these messages on the Terminal.

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://IP-ADDRESS/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

How do I get the last line where it says "Running on IP ADDRESS" as a string in Python? Need to get the IP address of the Flask server every time it is started up.

Comment: not sure if that helps, but it is supposed to be an input at the running stage: app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=5600) Maybe you can get it from here?